# Deleting a Char array from a binary tree

Tags: c, binary-tree

Title explains it all, something weird is going on with my delete function that i cant seem to figure out. I think its getting stuck on the recursion part of the program based off of standard print statements. If anyone can help that would be greatly appreciated

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>


typedef struct btree
{
    char name[10];
    //int data;
    struct btree *rlink;
    struct btree *llink;
}node;
void insert(node**, char[]);
void inorder(node*);
void preorder(node*);
void postorder(node*);
int charToNum(node*);
node* findmin(node*);
node* findmax(node*);
node* del(node*, char[]);

int main(void)
{
    node *root;
    root = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    root = NULL;
    int ch, x;
    x = 0;
    char num[10];
    while (1)
    {
        printf("\n 1.insert2.inorder3.preorder4.postorder5.findmin6.findmax7.Delete");
        printf("\n Enter your choice>");
        scanf("%d", &ch);
        switch (ch)
        {
        case 1:
            printf("\n Enter node to insert>");
            scanf("%s", &num);
            insert(&root, num);
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("\n inorder display");
            inorder(root);
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("\n pre-order display");
            preorder(root);
            break;
        case 4:
            printf("\n post-order display");
            postorder(root);
            break;
        case 5:
            printf("\n Min in the tree is %s", findmin(root)->name);
            break;
        case 6:
            printf("\n Max in the tree is %s", findmax(root)->name);
            break;
        case 7:
            printf("\n enter the node to delete>");
            scanf("%s", &num);
            root = del(root, num);
            break;

        case 8:
            exit(0);


        }
    }
}
void insert(node** h, char info[10])
{
    if (*h == NULL)
    {

        node *temp;
        temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        strcpy((temp->name), info);
        //temp->name = info;
        temp->llink = NULL;
        temp->rlink = NULL;
        *h = temp;
        printf("successfully added %s\n", temp->name);
    }
    else if (info > (*h)->name) {
        insert(&(*h)->rlink, info);
    }
    else if (info <(*h)->name)
        insert(&(*h)->llink, info);
}
void inorder(node* h)
{
    if (h != NULL)
    {
        inorder(h->llink);
        printf("%s->", h->name);
        inorder(h->rlink);
    }
}

void preorder(node* h)
{
    if (h != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s->", h->name);
        preorder(h->llink);

        preorder(h->rlink);
    }
}

void postorder(node* h)
{
    if (h != NULL)
    {

        postorder(h->llink);

        postorder(h->rlink);
        printf("%s->", h->name);
    }
}

node* findmin(node* h)
{
    if (h->llink == NULL)
        return h;
    else
        findmin(h->llink);
}

node* findmax(node* h)
{
    if (h->rlink == NULL)
        return h;
    else
        findmax(h->rlink);
}

node* del(node *h, char info[])
{

    if (h == NULL)
        return h;

    else if (info > h->name) {
        printf("info > h->name\n");
        h->rlink = del(h->rlink, info);
    }
    else if (info < h->name) {
        h->llink = del(h->llink, info);
        printf("info < h->name\n");
    }
    else
    {
        if (h->llink == NULL && h->rlink == NULL)
        {
            printf("first if excuting");
            /*node *tmp;
            tmp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
            tmp = h;*/
            h = NULL;

            return h;
        }
        else if (h->llink == NULL)
        {
            node *tmp;
            tmp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
            tmp = h;
            h = h->rlink;
            free(tmp);
            printf("else if finished\n");
        }
        else if (h->rlink == NULL)
        {
            printf("second else if is ecuting \n");
            node *tmp;
            tmp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
            tmp = h;
            h = h->llink;
            free(tmp);
            printf("second else if finished\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("final else  is excuting\n");
            node *tmp;
            tmp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
            tmp = findmin(h->rlink);
            strcpy((h->name),tmp->name);
            //h->name = tmp->name;
            h->rlink = del(h->rlink, tmp->name);
            free(tmp);
            printf("final else finished\n");
        }
    }
    return h;
}
```

Comment: `else if (info > h->name) {` is that supposed to be a string compare?

Comment: You allocate `root = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));`. All good there. But then you then you `root = NULL;` and ruin everything :p Oh never mind, you have checks, good good :)

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I was wondering the same thing. If anything, they'd just compare pointers, no?

Comment: @InternetAussie Yes, OP needs to use [`strcmp()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp).

Comment: @JohnnyMopp thats what i thought in for the insert function but that seemed to compare it , so i decided not to worry about it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon.  Although the code is there, but you've not created an MCVE ([MCVE]) yet because there is no information on the data you're using, the output you're getting, and the output you expect.  There's also room to think the code isn't as minimal as it could be — it isn't clear that `findmin()` is germane to your current problem (which is just as well since the code in it is broken because the function doesn't always return a value).